# How to take in-app photo with PhoneGap?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, camera, phonegap-plugins

I've noticed that certain apps (e.g., [Colorfy](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/colorfy-coloring-book-for/id1009442510?mt=8)) allow you to take a photo within the app that can then be further edited. Is there any way to do that with a PhoneGap app?

All the PhoneGap examples I've ever seen have you accessing `navigator.camera.getPicture`, which is fine, except that it requires you to jump over to the camera app to take the picture, confirm the picture you just took, etc. I'd really love to be able to skip all of that and take the picture directly in the app, but I'm not sure if it's possible.

If it is possible, please let me know how. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to create a custom Plugin for this to work.

**This will be the flow:**

• Call the PhoneGap plugin from webpage

• Plugin will open the camera view

• After image has clicked it is then encoded in base-64

• Send this base-64 encoded image to webpage using Plugin callback.

**Below code can be used for encoding the image:**

```
UIImage* image= <Image received from the camera>;
NSString *base64EncodedImage = [Base64 encode:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5)];
```

**Edit:**

A few sample plugins:

https://github.com/cordova-plugin-camera-preview/cordova-plugin-camera-preview

https://github.com/donaldp24/CanvasCameraPlugin

Comment: atulkhatri, thanks for your response. Are you saying that the plugin you're recommending above has the ability to open the camera view behind the scenes without it taking over the interface? Also, would you have to constantly poll the camera view in order to get the current image displayed on it and then constantly be encoding that image and displaying it within the app? I'm just trying to make sure that I understand what you're recommending correctly. Thanks.

Comment: No you don't have to constantly poll the camera. You just have to use your plugin and its plugin's responsibility to open the camera in native and send the image to your webpage in its callback. BTW updated my answer and added a few ready-to-use plugins for your use.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that. Those links look very promising as well. Thank you.

Comment: No problem, glad it helped.